# How to extract html element into a variable after data is successfully returned from an ajax response?

Tags: jquery

How to extract html element into a variable after data is successfully returned from an ajax response?

This is the ajax call containing the following returned data

```
   $.getJSON("test.php",function(data)
   {
        $.each(data, function(key, value)
        {
             alert(value); // this is working but don't know how to extract the strong element from the p element into a variable
        });
   });
```

I get the following html data returned from an ajax response

```
          <p id="testResults"><strong id="testNumber">Test 1</strong> passed - date </p>
```

How do I get the strong html element into a variable for later usage like this....

```
        var testNumberHtml = "<strong id='testNumber'>Test 1</strong>";
```

and then put the p element into another variable, like this...

```
       var testResultsHtml =  "<p id="testResults"> passed - date </p>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to do a little trickery to separate those. I would suggest having server side send them separated like this:

```
{p: "<p id="testResults"> passed - date </p>", 
 strong: "<p id="testResults"> passed - date </p>"}
```

If that is not an option, you can probably do it [like this in javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfXeX/2/):

html

```
<div id="contentResult" style="display:none;"></div>​
```

js

```
var jsonResult = '<p id="testResults"><strong id="testNumber">Test 1</strong> passed - date </p>';

var jsonDiv = document.createElement("div");
jsonDiv.innerHTML = jsonResult;
var content = document.getElementById("contentResult");
content.appendChild(jsonDiv);
var strongElement = document.getElementById("testNumber");
var strongCopy = $(strongElement).clone(true);
strongElement.parentNode.removeChild(strongElement);
var testResult = document.getElementById("testResults");
var testCopy = $(testResult).clone(true);
testResult.parentNode.removeChild(testResult);
jsonDiv.parentNode.removeChild(jsonDiv);
console.log(testCopy);
console.log(strongCopy);
```